# MDI Application - Cannot open child form

Tags: c++, c++builder, mdi, c++builder-6

I made 2 form. MainForm and ChildForm(I set become available forms)

design >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4XWf.png

when I want to call my ChildForm use this code

```
  void __fastcall TMainForm::ChildForm1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
      if(!ChildForm)
       { ChildForm =  new TChildForm(this); }
      else
       { ChildForm->WindowState=wsNormal; }
    }
```

and to close

```
void __fastcall TChildForm::FormClose(TObject *Sender,
  TCloseAction &Action)
 {
    Action=caFree;
 }
```

why when i open ChildForm then i close. and when to open again . ChildForm Can't open ??

#

Main Form

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h" //ChildForm
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMainForm *MainForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMainForm::ChildForm1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 if(!ChildForm)
{ ChildForm =  new TChildForm(this); }
else
{ ChildForm->WindowState=wsNormal; }
}
```

Comment: Something tells me that you need to set `ChildForm` to `NULL` as well in the body of `FormClose`.

Comment: What's the code in `TChildForm::TChildForm`? If it somehow keeps a copy of the pointer to `TMainForm` it gets, it should be possible to do tell it to reset the `ChildForm` pointer it holds.

Comment: @didierc: that is the correct answer, so you should post it as an answer, not a comment. However, i would suggest resetting the pointer in the child's destructor, not in the OnClose event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been discussed in the comments, and thanks to the help of @Remy Lebeau, in the `TMainForm` class, you need to set the `ChildFrom` pointer to `NULL` after having destroyed the form it points to. This may be accomplished in the destructor of the `TChildForm` class, by using the pointer of its owner that has been passed to it at construction time.

The issue is basically in that code snippet:

```
  if(!ChildForm)
   { ChildForm =  new TChildForm(this); }
  else
   { ChildForm->WindowState=wsNormal; }
```

The first time, everything works as planned. When `ChildForm` is destroyed however, the pointer isn't reset, and the next time `ChildForm` creation is requested, the first test fails, and of course the form isn't created.

So:

- make the `TChildForm` class keep a copy of its owner's pointer (you'll probably need to change the constructor prototype to the following:

  ```
  __fastcall TChildForm::TChildForm(TMainForm *owner)
  ```

  in order for `TChildForm` to know the *full type* of its owner (the IDE should `#include` the `TMainForm` header for you, or ask for the permission to do it).
- Create a method in `TMainForm` to handle `TChildForm` pointer reset, and give it the right access level for a `TChildForm` to invoke it.
- add a call to that method (ie. `owner->onChildFormTermination()` or something like that) in `~TChildForm` to let its owner know.

Note that my VCL-fu is a bit rusty (I haven't coded with C++Builder for 10+ years), there might be a more idiomatic way of writing this.